# Symfony 2 search form routing setting

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am making a basic search form with symfony 2. I have problem with configuration of routing.yml file.

**My routing.yml File**

```
adhl_front_search:
    pattern: /{_locale}/search
    defaults: { _controller: AdhlFrontBundle:Blog:search  }
    requirements:
        _locale: en
```

**My form code:**

```
<form method="get" action="{{ path('adhl_front_search') }}/">
      <input type="text" value="" name="keyword" />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**I get and want this url:**

```
app_dev.php/en/search/?keyword=computer
```

**Symfony Error:**

```
No route found for "GET /en/search/"
```

I don't know how to configure my url for search form. In my case it expect ?keyword=computer in routing.yml. If i do it like `pattern: /{_locale}/search/{keyword}` then form page gives error at `{{ path('adhl_front_search') }}`

Secondly, how can i pass the keyword (computer in above case) value to my controller? Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most simple way to do this is

```
pattern: /{_locale}/search/?keyword={key}
```

and in your controller expect the $key variable,
but this isn't the best way ...

however try to do this

```
pattern: /{_locale}/search/
```

I have this in one of my projects and it works

**edit 2:**
try this in your controller

```
  public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {   
        $keyword = $request->get('keyword');
```

Comment: I changed in routing.yml file as `pattern: /{_locale}/search/` i get `en/search/?keyword=computer` URL upon submitting the search form. I get this error `The controller for URI "/en/search/" is not callable.`

Comment: Ion i tried with `$keyword = $request->get('keyword');` and i received the value of keyword in my controller. My search form is working now with your kind help. Thank you very much.